# Problem updating to Python 3.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: installation, apt, upgrade, python3

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I wanted to upgrade the Python version to 3.3, but I am having some problems doing it.

Whenever I run this command,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
```

Can anyone tell me what is happening?

Comment: Maybe there are some package sources missing... Can you post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: By the way, it's 'Ubuntu 12.04' (not Linux). Ubuntu is not the *only* distribution of Linux and Linux does not necessarily mean 'Ubuntu'. Linux is merely the underlying kernel from which Ubuntu uses.

Comment: @chaos it say's no such file or directory found

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get update` first. Make sure you have an internet connection.

Comment: nope didn't worked instead got following errors  
    >E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11:   Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: Are you sure you have root privileges? You need to be root or issue `sudo` and get the password right (it's the password you use to login).

Comment: yeas it asks for password and i provide it

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally deleted your sources.list. To regenerate this file go to this [website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and choose the country and your os release. check all `Ununtu Banches` and `Ubuntu Updates` and if you want `Ubuntu Partner Repos` and `Ubuntu Extras Repos` and then generate the new file.

Now you have to copy the content into your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, create the file if its not existing yet, and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Your system should be up-to-date again now. And you should now be able to run your installation again:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: can you tell me how to create those directory and where

Comment: Create folder if not exist: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt` open the file with editor `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` copy the contents type "Ctrl-o" to save "enter" and "Ctrl-x" to exit.

Comment: still not working now it say's  Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: Then you have to delete the lock files `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and  `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` first.